# Decoding cyrillic %get[] parameter in Ajax form

Tags: webforms, uri, javascript, ajax

I have a request form in a popup window. It's located on a page of single product and must send product's name. This name's delivered using a hidden input field (Drupal Webform), which takes its value from %get[product]. The problem's that the site's in Russian so the result is url encoded and not readable.

The programmer who was asked to fix the form just replaced all Russian characters with corresponding English letters. But that's not a decision )

I can't just put php code in that field - Drupal doesn't understand it. Are there any other options?